# Passing adb shell commands into IntelliJ Android Launcher

Tags: android, intellij-idea, adb, android-gradle-plugin

I am building an Android application that is designed to help with load testing. When the app launches we are sending extra values to the main activity so that we can control what kind of load each app executes. Currently, we are doing this, scripted, via the terminal using adb directly which is pretty straight forward:

```
adb shell am start -e key1 value1 -e key2 value2 -n bla.bla/bla.MainActivity
```

For debugging purposes, I'd like to be able to do this from IntelliJ but I don't see anything in my run configuration screen that let's me pass anything to adb. Is this possible?

Comment: This seems like a neat technique.  How are you reading the extra values in the code?  The adb doc doesn't seem to describe the "-e" parameter.

Comment: getIntent().getStringExtra(). It's just like passing Extra values into an Intent from code. But you can pass them in via the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Might be waaaaaay late on this one, but you can always try the BashSupport plugin on the IntelliJ Repo.